# jquery tabs on enter key works only once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement the jquery tab which work on enter key so that on pressing enter key the control passes to the next i wrote the following code which works only once when the page is first loaded and when i again go on first tab and trying pressing enter key to go on the next tab it doesn't work. I am using jquery tabs http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/
 for this

```
$("#tab-div").keypress(function (e) {

        if (e.which == 13) {
            var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected");
            $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your console? Whenever something is "not working" that is usually what seems to be happening. Also, is there any possibility that you have more than one div with ID `tab-div`? You could run into problems binding to an ID if there is more than one of that ID

Comment: I have edited the question please check it now

Answer (score 0):

try to `bind` the event to the element or use `live`

```
$("#tab-div").live("keypress", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
        return true; //this might not be required
    }
});
```

Comment: I want that when the tab is on focus then on pressing of enter key it should move to the next tab. As of now if i enter on any of my textboxes then the focus is passed to the next tab.

Comment: I am using http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#mouseover but instead of mouseover i want it to be done on enter key.